# Text rendering issue in Safari on Mac with React contenteditable

Tags: reactjs, macos, safari, text-rendering

I'm encountering a problem with text rendering specifically on Safari on Mac with size greater than 13 inch (on 13 inch the text is shown normally), when using a **react-contenteditable**. The text is not displaying properly; it appears to be cut off or partially visible. When I click outside the text area of **react-contenteditable**, the text is then re -rendered properly and fully visible.

Here's a simplified version of the React component I'm using for the 'contenteditable' functionality:

```
   <ContentEditable
            id="custom-text-editable"
            className={classNames('textarea-input-gilroy', { 'gilroy-caret-style': toggleCaret })}
            onChange={onChangeText}
            onPaste={handlePasteInGpt}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            onClick={handleClickInsideDiv}
            html={chatLoading ? '' : valueHtml}
            suppressContentEditableWarning
            spellCheck="false"
            draggable={false}
            placeholder=""
            innerRef={contentEditableRef}
            disabled={chatLoading || isEditChatFlag}
          />
```

Here is a short video of the issue, showing text behavior on chrome and safari on the same device.

[Issue video link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CxeZ-HpV2Yma_tEE7cv_6YsPje8e18Qe?usp=sharing)